# Cannot run ng build in Angular 8

Tags: exception, angular8, ng-build

When I am creating an angular application and to deploy it I need to run the ng build command, earlier I used the command - `ng build` and it worked all fine.But now whenever I run the command ng build it throws error-

1. when I run just `**ng build**`

> An unhandled exception occurred: [BABEL] C:\Amigo
>   Technologies\Project_NG\project-farmer\dist\project-farmer\polyfills-es5.js:
>   Could not find plugin "proposal-numeric-separator". Ensure there is an
>   entry in ./available-plugins.js for it. (While processing: "C:\Amigo
>   Technologies\Project_NG\project-farmer\node_modules\@babel\preset-env\lib\index.js") See "C:\Users\akank\AppData\Local\Temp\ng-0s10Ll\angular-errors.log"
>   for further details.

2. If I run `**ng build --base-href = '/project-farmer/' --prod**`

> An unhandled exception occurred: Project ''/project-farmer/'' does not
>   support the 'build' target. See
>   "C:\Users\akank\AppData\Local\Temp\ng-Qw9n0d\angular-errors.log" for
>   further details.

Comment: This error sometimes appears when you have mismatched verisonos `angular` and `ng-cli`.